# "Could not find the main class: XX. Program will exit."

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have managed to run my jar file with a command prompt, but its always giving me a reponse of

> Could not find the main class: XX. Program will exit.

Please help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

See [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

> If you have an application bundled in a JAR file, you need some way to indicate which class within the JAR file is your application's entry point. You provide this information with the Main-Class header in the manifest, which has the general form:

```
Main-Class: classname
```

> The value classname is the name of the class that is your application's entry point.
>
> Recall that the entry point is a class having a method with signature

```
 public static void main(String[] args).
```

After you have set the Main-Class header in the manifest, you then run the JAR file using the following form of the java command:

```
java -jar JAR-name
```

The main method of the class specified in the Main-Class header is executed.

---

> We first create a text file named Manifest.txt with the following contents:

```
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass
```

> **Warning**: The text file **must end with a new line or carriage return**. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.
>
> We then create a JAR file named MyJar.jar by entering the following command:

```
jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class
```

> This creates the JAR file with a manifest with the following contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass
```

> When you run the JAR file with the following command, the main method of MyClass executes:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. The problem was that Windows 10 suddenly decided to set my workspace folder to read-only.

After removing the read-only checkmark in the folder's options, the problem was solved.