# No main found when executing jar

Tags: java, jar, javac

http://pastebin.com/1btVw8Cb

There are two classes in the above code.

So above is my code which is working fine when I hit run in Eclipse, runs fine in Netbeans as well.

I am trying to create a standalone application, a jar file.

The error I get when I double my jar is:

Could not find the main class: NewJFrame. Program will exit. 
I get the following from the command promt:

```
E:\Java Programs\Eclipse Workspace\test3\src\test3>java testT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: testT/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testT.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: testT.jar.  Program will exit.
```

I followed the command from here: ["Could not find the main class: XX. Program will exit."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417328/could-not-find-the-main-class-xx-program-will-exit)
So this is what I am typing in the command promt to create my jar:

```
E:\Java Programs\Eclipse Workspace\test3\src\test3>jar cfm MyJar.jar manifest.tx
t *.class SINGLE.TXT
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncm1q.jpg

Some shots above I took to show the process.

So I think the problem could be error when I do javac? But it builds fine and runs fine in netbeans and eclipse >< Please help.

Comment: `java testT.jar` attempts to run a class called `jar` in a package called `testT`.

Comment: What about the `maifest.mf` file? Have mentioned the main class in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is now working. I have not changed anything, maybe the memory got curroupted and that is why it was giving me problems. I think restart the computer is what fixed it. But yea, I don't know for sure what was wrong, though it is working fine now. So thank you for your help guys

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `-jar` flag.

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html says

> #### JAR Files as Applications
>
> You can run JAR-packaged applications with the Java interpreter. The basic command is:
>
> ```
> java -jar jar-file
> ```
>
> The `-jar` flag tells the interpreter that the application is packaged in the JAR file format. You can only specify one JAR file, which must contain all the application-specific code.

and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html explains how to put a manifest in the jar.

> The `m` option indicates that you want to merge information from an existing file into the manifest file of the JAR file you're creating.

Comment: that did not work. I got the following: http://pastebin.com/npm3ksNd Also, I want this app to be able to run by just double clicking it, because I plan to turn it into an applet.

Comment: are you sure your main class is within the test3 package and is called NewJFrame?

Comment: yes, if you look at my screenshots, you'll see that NewJFram is there and if you follow the pastebin's link you will see the main method there.

Comment: @NomanArain, the name of your class in the `Main-Class` manifest entry should be `test3.NewJFrame` not `test3/NewJFrame`.

Comment: Mike I changed my mainifest to say Main-Class: test3.NewJFrame but it still gives me the same error, main cannot be found. Error: Could not find the main class: test3.NewJFrame. Program will exit.

Comment: @NomanArain, Please extract your manifest via `jar xf MyJar.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and post its content in your question so we can help debug.

Comment: I have taken the code out of package, http://pastebin.com/pSrjVCeL this has the code and at the boom i pasted the manifest.mf

Comment: @NomanArain, In your manifest, you have the line `Main-Class: NewJFrame`.   That is missing a package name.

Comment: Mike, I took out the package from my code. So my programmed is not packaged anymore.

Comment: Your screenshot shows CODE not .class files. You have to add the compiled files to the JAR, the source won't do you any good.

Comment: @Jochen I am running this command: jar cfm MyJar.jar manifest.tx
t *.class SINGLE.TXT, so it's only adding .class classes.

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_31 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: NewJFrame

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
Main-class: Splash
```

part to Manifest file. set Main class name instead Splash

That will work...