# Java 7 vs Java6 bug

Tags: java, runtime, startup

I am having a problem where if a computer is using anything lower than the latest java7 runtime environment, when they click on the jar file, it says, "Cannot find the main class: xxx. Program will exit'.

I don't understand why it does this on java6 Runtime. Any ideas? Thanks guys.

Comment: Did you compile your jar with JDK 7?

Comment: Does the main class reference a JDK 7 class? The class might not even be able to be loaded in JDK 6, leading to this misleading error message. Could you provide the code of the main class?

Comment: If this is related to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051838/cannot-find-main-class-java-error) it's likely not appropriate to ask it again.

Comment: I'll bet it's not a bug.  Better to assume that you've misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong at the OS level rather than in Java.  For instance, the accepted answer to [Executing a Jar on Vista with a double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354664/executing-a-jar-on-vista-with-a-double-click) explains that you need to have the file associations set up correctly on a Windows OS for double-click to work on a JAR file.