# Java application fails to start

Tags: java

I am currently using Ubuntu 11.10 and java SE 1.6.0_26. I am trying to run a very simple  "Hello World" app. I placed the the java file `HelloWorld.java` on the Home folder. I compiled it using the command `javac HelloWorld.java`. I think its working because it doesn't show any compilation error and a `HelloWorld.class` is created.

When I typed the command `java HelloWorld` I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: HelloWorld.  Program will exit.
```

BTW, here is my java code:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which folder are you running the java command from?

Comment: @AmitBhargava Home folder. The same directory where my HelloWorld.java and HelloWorld.class resides.

Comment: Could you please try the following : java -classpath HelloWorld

Comment: Can you give us the output of  `ls -l` on home directory

Comment: This looks like a classpath problem. There is some information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120662/could-not-find-the-main-class-program-will-exit You may need to include -classpath .

Comment: @AmitBhargava It shows a long lis of instructions. The first instruction is Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

Comment: Yet more information on this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417328/could-not-find-the-main-class

Comment: @JigarJoshi It shows 3 files: HelloWorld.class, HelloWorld.java, and HelloWorld.java~.

Comment: Just wanted the output to check if you have appropriate permission, Generally user in home folder has the access but just to check

Comment: @JigarJoshi Thanks I didn't know that Ubuntu has some permission issues. Very new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be that the file is not in your classpath..try the following command:

```
java -classpath . HelloWorld
```

V

Comment: I find it strange that Java would have an issue with the classpath, unless it was improperly installed.  Normally, one shouldn't have this issue with non-package Java files on (U)buntu, but this is always a good thing to know anyway.

Comment: @TheOnlyIdiot - Like he said, the problem is that the class was not on your classpath.  It is all explained in the manual entry for the `java` command.  In particular the page about setting your classpath.

Comment: @Makoto - (I suspect that the OP has set $CLASSPATH to something that doesn't work ...)

Comment: yeah..the $CLASSPATH is generally at fault..I think the main reason is that by default, Ubuntu ships with OpenJDK and not Oracle JVM which requires you to set the CLASSPATH while the latter doesn't..either you can switch or add this line to your .bashrc file in the home directory..
`export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:.`

You would have to then type `source .bashrc`